# Why does my code skip the part where the user inputs their current/target industry?

Tags: java

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScreenCandidates
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//About You
System.out.println("\t\tAbout You");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("\nName: ");
String name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nLocation: ");
String location = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nLanguages: ");
String languages = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nHighest Level of Education: ");
String education = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nGPA: ");
double gpa = scan.nextDouble();
//Your Professional Goals
System.out.println("\t\tYour Professional Goals ");
System.out.print("\nIndustry (current or target): ");
String industry = scan.nextLine();
//Work History
System.out.println("\t\tWork History ");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("\nCurrent Title: ");
String currentTitle = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nCurrent Employer: ");
String currentEmployer = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nPrevious Titles: ");
String previosTitle1 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nFormer Employer: ");
String formerEmployer = scan.nextLine();
//Qualifications, Skills and Accomplishments
}
}
```

When I run the code:

About You

Name: Peter

Location: 07430

Languages: German

Highest Level of Education: Associates Degree

GPA: 3.95
        Your Professional Goals

**Industry (current or target):         Work History**

Current Title: Java Programmer

Current Employer: Verizon

Previous Titles: Teacher

Former Employer: Jonas Salk Middle School

Answer (score 0):

Add a `scan.nextLine()` after `double gpa = scan.nextDouble();` to get the `newline` left by call to `nextDouble()`